# is bellman-ford can be done in a single iteration?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

Does every graph have an order of the edges such that after running a single iteration of Bellman-Ford algorithm according to this order, every vertex is labeled with it's shortest path to the source ?

i'm quiet sure that the answer is yes, but i can't think of an Algorithm that is able to find the order of edges, thanks =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort a shortest path tree topologically.

Comment: That makes sense! But It's better to run dfs/bfs on shortest path tree (start from source and use edges (u,v)=(parent[v],v)), it's much simplier to code I think.